# How to use a pdfView widget with MVVM (with data binding)?

Tags: android, pdf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a pdf file on my android device's storage that I'd like to show using the pdfView widget. I have done this before following the MVP pattern and I accomplished it by doing this in my fragment activity class:

```
PDF pdfView;
public static String SAMPLE_FILE; //this is where I put in my file location

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

      pdfView = (PDFView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
      pdfView.fromFile(new File(SAMPLE_FILE))
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .onRender(this)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .load();

}
```

What I would like to do now is to implement the pdf View using MVVM.

The problem I have is that when I try to implement something similar in my view model,  this line:

```
pdfView = (PDFView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
```

returns a null object.

Apparently using findViewById is a no-no when using MVVM, how might I implement this without using findViewById?

Im using this to display pdfs: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: Get your UI logic out of your view model. Wrap your UI logic in a UserControl that has DependencyProperties that your view model binds to (I dunno in this case, but I'd guess your VM would probably be deciding which PDF file the user wants, so FileName would be a viable candidate). Respond to changes to the DP to update the view.  Remember, MVVM != no codebehind.

Comment: @Will Thank you so much for responding. I was wondering if you could help me out with some more details about implementing a UserControl with DependencyProperties and how it updates the view? Examples or links to it will be very much appreciated. Forgive the rookie questions, MVVM is really new to me. Do I call an adapter in my View using <`app:adapter="@{ViewModel.GetAdapter}"`> to show this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was an android question.  It's out of my wheelhouse. Look into making custom controls for android apps.

Comment: I see. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

```
object PDFViewBindingAdapter {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("pdfFile")
    fun setImageURI(pdfView: PDFView, file: File) {
        file?.let {
            pdfView.fromFile(file)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .load()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use binding adapter, then you can bind the file (taken from your viewmodel) in your layout: bind:pdfFile="@{viewModel.pdfFile}"